# NDepend: Check if a type implements a generic interface

Tags: ndepend

Is there a way to check if a type is implementing a generic type with certain generic parameters using NDepend?

The implemented interface property returns the generic type, but without specific generic parameters. So IList for example, instead I want to no if a certain type implements IList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a query like:

```
from t in Types where t.Implement("System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>")
select t
```

but you cannot write a query like:

```
from t in Types where t.Implement("System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Int32>") 
select t
```

So the answer is no *to Is there a way to check if a type is implementing a generic type with certain generic parameters using NDepend?*

This situation might evolve in the future, feel free to add request to the [NDepend User Voice page](http://ndepend.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thank.s I created a feature request: http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4919844-be-able-to-check-if-a-type-is-implementing-a-gener